# SQL error: The (maximum) expected data length is 510, while the returned data length is 1010

Tags: sql-server, odbc, linked-server, datalength

I have a data source from Cloudera Hive ODBC in MS SQL Server connected via a linked server. When I try to query one of the tables it throws an error as follows ' OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' for linked server 'CL' returned data that does not match the expected data length for column 'referralreason'.The (maximum) expected data length is 510, while the returned data length is 1010.'
I tried to cast it to varchar, changed the connection string criteria by adding OLEDBReturnCharAsWChar=0, tried using only open query no luck, some examples I tried are below:

1. SELECT CAST(Notes1 AS VARCHAR(MAX))

   - CAST(Notes2 AS VARCHAR(MAX))
   - CAST(Notes3 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Notes
     FROM OPENQUERY(CL, 'SELECT
     LEFT(CAST(referralreason AS VARCHAR(1000), 400) AS Notes1
     ,SUBSTRING(CAST(referralreason AS VARCHAR(1000),401,800) AS Notes2
     ,SUBSTRING(CAST(referralreason AS VARCHAR(1000),801,1200) AS Notes3
     FROM from REFERRAL')
2. declare @my varchar(max)
   set @my = 'select * from [REFERRAL]'
   execute (@my) AT [CL]
3. select * from OPENQUERY(CL, 'select  CAST(referralreason AS NVARCHAR(4000)) as refreason from REFERRAL')

Comment: Sounds like there is a mixup between varchar (1 byte per character) and nvarchar (2 bytes per character).

Comment: Seems like there is an `nvarchar(255)` column involved that's not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @AaronBertrand How can i correct that error?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I copy-pasted the error as is. Not sure what you are asking exactly?